# In R when using count function, how to just extract the int value from the tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

For example:

```
data("cars")
count(cars)
```

I will get a tibble of 1x1, but I would like to assign the count which was 54 into a variable to use later. If I use Select I also get a tibble back, I just want a variable with an int value.

Comment: `Warning message: In data("titanic") : data set ‘titanic’ not found`. Please post the call to `library()` that loads the package where we can find the dataset. (There are many titanic datasets around.)

Comment: `count(iris)` returns a tibble, `NROW(iris)` returns a number. It's upper case because the lower case version only "works" for objects with the `dim` attribute set, `NROW` works also for vectors. See `nrow(1:5)` versus `NROW(1:5)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas changed it to cars to make it universally happy = )

Comment: NROW is good, I can assign that to a variable and reuse it for equations, thanks for this! @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data("cars")
variable <- nrow(cars)

# alternatively
library(tidyverse)
variable <- count(cars) %>% .$n

# alternatively 2
library(tidyverse)
variable <- count(cars) %>% pull(n)
```

Comment: I like the alternative, will use that! Any guide, documentation on using the .$n? I understand the column name is n, but I'm surprised how you can just put period and reference the column like that.

Comment: The . stands for "what is on the left side of the pipe operator" (i.e. this %>%). Since on the left side, there is a data frame with column named n, you can use the accessor (i.e. $). The accessor allows you to select any column from a data frame.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: 2 %>% sum(., 1)

Hopefully the above may illustrate how the dot works. Instead of sum(2, 1), you can use the above code. It should produce the exact same result.